# C++ programing error

Tags: c++, acc

I am new to C++ programming.
So I was trying my luck executing some small programs.
I am working on [HP-UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX) which has a compiler whose 
executable is named *aCC*.

I am trying to execute a small program

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
class myclass {
public:
    int i, j, k; 
};

int main()
{
    myclass a, b;
    a.i = 100; 
    a.j = 4;
    a.k = a.i * a.j;
    b.k = 12; 
    cout << a.k << " " << b.k;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this it gives me an error:

```
 > aCC temp.cpp
Error 697: "temp.cpp", line 2 # Only namespace names are valid here.
    using namespace std;
                    ^^^
```

What exactly is the problem?
Is `std` not considered as a namespace in the aCC compiler or is there some serious drawback with aCC?

If I change the `<iostream.h>` to `<iostream>`, I get some more errors added as below.

```
>aCC temp.cpp
Error 112: "temp.cpp", line 1 # Include file <iostream> not found.
    #include <iostream>
             ^^^^^^^^^^
Error 697: "temp.cpp", line 2 # Only namespace names are valid here.
    using namespace std;
                    ^^^
Error 172: "temp.cpp", line 14 # Undeclared variable 'cout'.
    cout << a.k << " " << b.k;
```

Comment: even if i chnage  <iostream.h> to <iostream> its giving me an error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which version of aCC are you using?  Older versions used a pre-standard STL implemenntation that put everything in the global namespace (i.e. didn't use the std namespace)

You might also need to use the -AA option when compiling.  This tells the compiler to use the newer 2.x version of HP's STL library.

```
>aCC -AA temp.cpp
```

And it should always be

```
<iostream>  

<iostream.h>
```

is from a pre-standard implementation of the language, though it is usually shipped so as to maintain backwards compatibility with older code.

Comment: Thanks a lot glen.this worked.but by default which version is selected?

Comment: You should aim to use standard C++ all the time.  So you should always compile with the -AA flag.  It's a pain that aCC defaults to the non-standard version, but it can't be helped.  One thing to be aware of, all libraries that you link against must also have been compiled with the -AA flag, or you'll run into problems

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Instead of:

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

**iostream.h** is an old style header in which all functions are exposed in global namespace. naturally in such a case, using namespace std may not work since std namespace is probably not exposed by iostream.h header (in this compiler). As explained above, try with # include  which is a new style C++ standard library header. (thanks **Shailesh Kumar** for the comment! included it in the answer).

Comment: iostream.h is an old style header in which all functions are exposed in global namespace. naturally in such a case, using namespace std may not work since std namespace is probably not exposed by iostream.h header (in this compiler). 

As explained above, try with # include <iostream> which is a new style C++ standard library header.